# Convert a SortedList to a List

Tags: java, android, list, sortedlist

Is there a way to convert android.support.v7.util.SortedList to java.util.List? (Or any other subclass) The only way I see is to go through the SortedList and add the elements one by one to a List, however this seems ugly and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: `SortedList` is a class and `List` is an interface, so you are maybe talking about `ArrayList`, but not `List`.

Have you tried with `arraylist.addAll(sortedList)`? But I don't think it will work, I am checking that `SortedList` doesn't implement `Collection`...

You can easily go from an `ArrayList` to a `SortedList`, though. Maybe you can refactor your code and handle an `ArrayList` from the very beginning, convert it to a `SortedList` for your needs, and then keep using the original `ArrayList`. Does it need to be a `SortedList` right from the beginning?